# Unable to start Google Cloud Profiler due to error: Unable to find the job id or job name from env var

Tags: google-cloud-platform, etl, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-profiler

We followed the **Cloud Profiler** [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/profiling-a-pipeline#enable_for_pipelines) to *enable* the Cloud Profiler for our Dataflow jobs and the Profiler is failing to start.

The issue is, Cloud Profiler needs `JOB_NAME` and `JOB_ID` environment vars to start but the worker VM has only the `JOB_ID` env var but the `JOB_NAME` is missing.

The question is why the `JOB_NAME` env var is missing?

**Logs:**

```
jsonPayload: {
    job: "2022-09-16 13 41 20-1177626142222241340"
    logger: "/us/local/lib/pvthon3.9/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/worker/sdk_worker_main.pv:177"
    message: "Unable to start google cloud profiler due to error:   Unable to find the job id or job name from envvar"
    portability_worker_1d: "sdk-0-13"
    thread: "MainThread"
    worker: "description-embeddings-20-09161341-k27g-harness-qxq2"
}
```

**Following done so far:**

1. **Cloud Profiler API** enabled for the project
2. Projects have enough **quota**.
3. the **Service Account** for the Dataflow job has appropriate permissions for Profiler.
4. Following options added to the pipeline
   `--dataflow_service_options=enable_google_cloud_profiler`
5. `enable_google_cloud_profiler` and `enable_google_cloud_heap_sampling` flags specified as additional **experiments** to deploy our pipeline from Dataflow templates.

---

**Edit:** Found the cause.

The provisioning API is returning an empty `JOB_NAME`, causing boot.go to set the `JOB_NAME` env var to "", which causes the Python SDK code to fail when trying to activate **googlecloudprofiler.**

There is an open issue on [IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/240585931) regarding this.

Comment: Please don't use screenshots. They may not outlive the Stack overflow post and they inhibit copy-and-paste'ing.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Is your concern that, even though a Job name was set when the Job was created, that it's not being provided through the environment at runtime?

Comment: @DazWilkin exactly. Dataflow should provide these values at runtime but it's only providing the JOB ID. The `JOB NAME` is missing.

Comment: Perhaps: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/240585931 ?